# Question about projective closure of a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am working on a problem, and I wanted someone to look over my work and comment of I am on the right track.

I have a polynomial $f\in K[x]$, where $K$ is an algebraically closed field, and $d=\deg f\ge3$. Then we have a variety defined by $h(x,y)=y^2-f(x)$. Now we want to show that the projective closure of this variety intersects the line at infinity at a unique point with multiplicity $d-2$.

My thoughts are that the projective closure is defined by the homogenization of the given polynomial $h(x,y)$. I will call it $H$, thus we have $H(x,y,z)=z^{d-2}y^2 - f(x,z)$. Then when we intersect this with the line at infinity $z=0$ we get $H(x,y,0)= cx^d$ where $c  \in K$.

Now I feel shady because I think the point of intersection has to be $[0,1,0]$. The multiplicity of the point should be where there is a partial derivative that does not automatically vanish at this point, but because the factor with $y$ is $z^{d-2}y^2$ we must take at least $d-2$ partial derivatives with respect to $z$ to have something survive.

Comment: Doesn't Bèzout's theorem imply that the multiplicity of the intersection is $d$?

Comment: I mean I know that by Bezout's theorem the intersection should be d * 1. But the problem is correct, it is my solution that is under question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we instead ask the question:

> What is the multiplicity $\mu_P(Y)$ of the (unique) intersection point $P \in Y \cap V(z)$ on $Y$?

then the answer is $d-2$. Note this is different from the intersection multiplicity of $Y$ and $V(z)$; in general, you get the inequality $(Y \cdot Z)_P \ge \mu_P(Y) \cdot \mu_P(Z)$ (see §3.3 in [Fulton's book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf)).

One definition of multiplicity $\mu_P(Y)$ is the following. Let $Y$ be defined in an affine chart containing $P$ by $f(x,y)$. After linear change of coordinates, $P = (0,0)$. Then, you can write
$$f(x,y) = f_0(x,y) + f_{1}(x,y) + \cdots$$
where each $f_i(x,y)$ is homogeneous of degree $i$. The multiplicity $\mu_P(Y)$ is then the smallest degree $i$ that appears.

This is equivalent to what I think is your condition on partial derivatives, *but only necessarily in characteristic zero* ([Fulton](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf), Problem 3.5). If you edit your question or comment with the definition you are working with, then I can compare the two definitions if you'd like.

Now the computation is actually not too hard. We pass to the affine chart $y \ne 0$, in which the curve's equation is given by
$$z^{d-2} - f(x,z) = 0.$$
But $f(x,z)$ is homogeneous of degree $d$. So the multiplicity is indeed $d-2$.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the problem is not correct: Bezout forces the intersection to have degree $d$ (as Charlie points out).

At any rate, once you have that $H(x,y,0) = cx^d$ you are basically done, since $x^d$ vanishes at $0$ on $\mathbb{A}^1$ with order $d$. One way to define intersection multiplicity at your point is as the $k$-dimension of $k[x,z] / (z , H(x,0,z)) = k[x] / (x^d)$, which is $d$.

Your reasoning with the partial derivatives is definitely shady ... at least, I don't see how to make it precise. But that is not saying much.

How are you defining intersection multiplicity? (There are several (agreeing) definitions.)

Comment: How we defined the multiplicity was as the smallest m such that there exists $ \frac{\partial f(a,b,c)}{\partial x^i \partial y^j \partial z ^k} \not = 0$ Also I agree this seems odd the problem does not seem congruent. I will confirm that the problem is correctly typed. Thank you

Comment: @Kori I don't really understand your definition, the intersection multiplicity should involve two curves and a point in their intersection. But in your non-equality there is only $f$.... and also, what does $m$ refer to?

Comment: m refers to i+j+k=m. This is the definition given in Kirwan's book.